# Changing transition of navigationbar when pushing

Tags: react-native

I use Navigator for navigation in my app and use different transitions (sceneconfigs) for different pushes. However, the transition of the navigation bar is not affected: for all pushes it animates from right to left even though sceneconfig is changed.

[image: gif]

When pressing the left button the view is transitioned from left to right using

```
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft
```

Yet as you can see, the content of of the navigation bar is transitioned from right to left.

How can I modify this behaviour? I need the navigation bar transition to be in line with the chosen sceneconfig..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to choose from the following default SceneConfigs

```
PushFromRight
FloatFromRight
FloatFromLeft
FloatFromBottom
FloatFromBottomAndroid
FadeAndroid
HorizontalSwipeJump
HorizontalSwipeJumpFromRight
VerticalUpSwipeJump
VerticalDownSwipeJump
```

If you want to know more- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js

Comment: This is what I am doing, but these does not affect the transition of the navigation bar, only the main view right?

Comment: @pinewood Yes. Navigation bar transition cannot be changed. Only the main view transition is affected using these SceneConfigs.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 files with navigationbar styles - one for iOS and one for Android:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBarStylesIOS.js

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBarStylesAndroid.js

Here you can modify the transition of the navigationbar components - left button, title and right button.